# make the data into an array and get the values

Tags: php, arrays

I have the data in my table like this

```
Arabic,Assamese,Azerbaijani,Belarusian
```

I want to show the data in an array so that I can use foreach and get the values for the array. So can someone tell me how to make it as an array and get values?

Comment: Hint: [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), generally the first function that many PHP developers ever learn

Answer (score 0):

Use [**explode**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function

```
$database_value = $db['your_data'];

$value_array = explode(',',$database_value);

print_r($value_array);


foreach ($value_array as $value){
   echo $value.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Arabic,Assamese,Azerbaijani,Belarusian";

$language_array= explode(',',$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have perform the query to the database and already has the data you can use  [**explode function**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). See this [**DEMO**](https://eval.in/191653).

```
$data = $row['data_from_table']; //your data is Arabic,Assamese,Azerbaijani,Belarusian

$exp = explode(",", $data);

foreach ($exp as $value){
echo $value;
echo PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```